# Missing Bitcoins

Tags: transactions

I sent 2btc between accounts and they have left one account but never arrived in the other account. This is over a day ago and the transaction has at least 20 conformations and is showing up when I track it on blockchain. It is just not appearing in the received wallet. Please advise? The address is fine: 1EkgFM6fx3Fq4XvEneuVwk3f8ET7PX8fj

Comment: I assume you are sure that the receiving address is correct and yours. Is your receiving wallet synchronized with the network?

Comment: Which client are you using to receive the coins, and are the confirmed already?

Comment: I looked the transaction up, it had plenty confirmations.

Answer (score 1):

If the transaction is in the blockchain, the Bitcoins are in the receiving address. If some particular client doesn't report them, that most likely means that it hasn't yet seen, or correctly processed, the block the transaction took place in. It could mean some other issue with that client. But the coins are there -- all it takes for a Bitcoin transaction to be received is for the transaction to be included in a block that's in the block chain.